# Freshly Installed Ubuntu 22.04 Persistant Startup Errors

Tags: 22.04, freeze

I'm new to Linux. I need some help figuring out what these errors mean as I am 80% sure they have something to do with my system freezing randomly which only a hard reset can fix at this time. Here are the errors:

```
12:30:20 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
12:30:15 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
12:30:14 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
12:30:05 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
12:30:05 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
12:30:03 kernel: spi-nor spi0.0: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: c2 75 18 c2 75 18
```

Comment: Did you verify the ISO you made the Live Media from before making the boot device? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Answer (score 2):

After much troubleshooting and research, turns out most of the above log entries are common and ultimately irrelevant. I have however discovered that my issue is due to an Intel WiFi driver problem. After disabling WiFi in the Bios, and using LAN instead, I have not encountered another random freeze again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: Thanks for circling back.